# C#. Как получить количество цифр, идущих после запятой?

Tags: c#

Например, **2.1563** - 4 цифры после запятой, **15** - 0.

Comment: Не обязательно на c#, главное - принцип нахождения.

Comment: Какой тип у значения: float, double, decimal? А может string? Может ли быть значение в экспоненциальной форме?

Comment: что за страшные слова?) Спасибо, уже нашёл решение, всё легче чем я думал

Comment: Ну как обычно: возьми значение неизвестного типа (то есть вообще непонятно, что это) и сделай из него конфетку.

Comment: Советую обратить внимание: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493771/5045688

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, навскидку написал пример

```csharp
Console.Write("Введите число: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (double.TryParse(input, out double number))
{
    string[] tokens = number.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split(".");
    int length = tokens.Length > 1 ? tokens[1].Length : 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Число содержит {0} знаков после запятой", length);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Не удалось распознать число");
}
```

Comment: а какие библиотеки?) ```CultureInfo.IvariantCulture``` - показывает ошибку.
Если что, пишу в Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Извиняюсь, подчёркивает только ```CultureInfo```: "не существует в данном контексте"

Comment: @ВладимирПечерский, нужно `using System.Globalization`

Answer (score 2):

Вариант №1:

```
    static int GetDecimalDigitsCount(double number)
    {
        string str = number.ToString(new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." });
        return str.Contains(".") ? str.Remove(0, Math.Truncate(number).ToString().Length + 1).Length : 0;
    }
```

Вариант №2:

```
    static int GetDecimalDigitsCount(double number)
    {
        string[] str = number.ToString(new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." }).Split('.');
        return str.Length == 2 ? str[1].Length : 0;
    }
```

Использование:

```
int count = GetDecimalDigitsCount(2.1563); //count = 4
int count = GetDecimalDigitsCount(2); //count = 0
```

Метод можно корректировать, к примеру, на вход будет строка с разделителем запятая и т.д.

Comment: Метод `double.ToString` имеет четыре перегрузки. Следует указывать `FormatProvider` и не гадать, что там будет в качестве разделителя - запятая, точка...

Comment: [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator?view=netcore-3.1) - так можно узнать разделитель.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение, подправил